# Is it possible to display a dynamic count/number alongside the static tab name/text in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic question in React JS. I have 3 tabs titled(Employees, Customers & Managers) where clicking on each tab will switch to the corresponding view. Let's say all 3 tabs are in same TabList component(same heirarchy/level)

I want to display the count also alongside the tab text using a variable. For example...

Employees(3)
Customers(5)
Managers(2)

Is it possible to display the dynamic count(integer/number) alongside the static tab text/name in React? The count represents number of employees or customers etc. I can increment the count according to number of employees or managers etc in each view. Just want to know if its possible to concatenate this dynamic count(using a variable) with the static tab text/label

Comment: Yes, it is easy <TabTitle> Employees ({numberOfEmployees}) </TabTitle>

Comment: Is this for react or react-native ?

Comment: Its for React JS

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I think you can do that. Use a state for the count/number so that your component will update every time the value changes.

Comment: Thank you, so i can display dynamic text including variables in the Tab name?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending "name" of the tab as a prop like this `<Tab name="Employees">` or `<Tab name={tabName}>` you can use template literal(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Example: <Tab name={`Employess ${countState}`}>. If you are nesting names within `Tab` component you may look to @Noor Nawaz comment=> `<Tab>Employess ({count})</Tab>`. And yes, you can display states dynamically with texts.